# Search street names and stores simultaneously

Tags: android, search

I've been building an app that runs of the Google Maps API but pulls from a separate database of markers I've manually entered. This has caused some issues with the search bar. Now the search bar only will search using keywords found in my database and will no longer pull from the Google database of all streets, cities, and states. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks

Edit for more detail:  We built a separate database of specific stores to be found. When you open the app, you will see a lot of markers with preset places and information. Typing anything in the search bar only pulls from those markers. It will only search from the information within the scope of the screen that are markers. For example, I might have a McDonald's set as a marker in my database in the city of Dallas. Typing "McDonald's" will remove all markers to just show that one. But if I'm in New York City and want to see what's in Dallas, typing "Dallas" will pull up an empty search instead of taking me to Dallas, Texas. I'm trying to find a way where it will do both. I can search from the names of the stores in my database and also the names of streets, cities, etc.

Comment: not getting u,please explain in detail edit your post